# I'm new to constructors, how am i going to pass an int for a string?

Tags: java, constructor

Everything was going okay until i realized that i needed to incorporate a testcase for my Card class. I've seen some posts similar to this but none that gave me the hints i needed to continue. I'm stuck :(

And no where in the description do they mention array's so i don't believe i can take the easy way out of this one.

Here is a description of the assignment : Create four constants representing the suits with the following values: Clubs 0, Diamonds 1, Hearts 2, and Spades 3.

Create two constants named ranks and suits that the toString method will use to convert the card to a string. Use an initializer list to create a constant named ranks that holds the ranks of the cards: Ace, Two, Three, … King. Use an initializer to create a second constant named suites that holds the names of the suits: Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades.

In the code block below, the twoOfClubs is passing a 1, and a 0. The 1 would represent the Rank and 0 would represent the suit?

So the 1 would be the TWO and the 0 would be the CLUBS, i get this, but how do i alter my constructor so that it knows a 1 is rank 2 and a 0 is rank CLUBS?

```
int testNum = 1;
Card twoOfClubs = new Card(1, 0);
System.out.println(testNum + ": " +
  (twoOfClubs.toString().equals("Two of Clubs -- points: 0") 
   ? "Pass" : "Fail"));
```

this code is what will be in CardTest

now my Card class is found here,

```
public class Card
{

    private final int CLUBS = 0;
    private final int DIAMONDS = 1;
    private final int HEARTS = 2;
    private final int SPADES = 3;

    private int points = 0;

    private String RANK;
    private String SUIT;



    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Card
     */
    public Card(String _rank, String _suit)
    {
        this.RANK = _rank;
        this.SUIT = _suit;

    }


    public void setRank(String _rank)
    {
        this.RANK = _rank;
    }

    public String getRank()
    {
        return this.RANK;
    }

    public void setSuit(String _suit)
    {
        this.SUIT = _suit;
    }

    public String getSuit()
    {
        return this.SUIT;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.RANK + " of " + this.SUIT + " -- points: " + this.points;
    }
}
```

the bit of code that is listed at the top will not compile obviously because i'm passing it two int's as opposed to the Two strings that it asked for..

EDIT 1:

My new translateSuit method is saying that it is missing a return statement?

```
private String translateSuit(int _suit)
    {
        switch(_suit)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Clubs";
            case 1:
                return "Spades";
            case 2:
                return "Hearts";
            case 3:
                return "Diamonds";
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Suit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just change all of the `String` to `int` in your `Card` class, except for the `toString` method

Comment: wouldnt that just change it from a string to constructing just int's? like rank "Two" will now be just 2 which has no real value here, like instead of Two of Kings, it will just be 1 of 0

Comment: From the look of your code, I assumed your problem was a type safety issue. Your assignment states "*the **`toString()`** method will use to convert to `String`*", which by your code it seems as if your class is expecting `String` in the first place

Comment: hmmm very good point, gives me a couple more ideas

Comment: When I said it was time to write a new question, I literally meant a brand new question.  Don't feel shy about asking more than one question so long as it's on topic.

Comment: No.  As in click the "Ask Question" button and create a new question.  You don't want to invalidate the answers on this question, which is what is resulting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing here is that the numbers are representing the actual words instead of you passing them in.

So, 1 represents the value 2, and 0 represents the suit "Clubs".

**Do not pass `String`s in, just pass `int`s.**

In your `toString` method is where the conversion has to happen.  Here's a snippet of how you'd go about determining the suit and the rank - I've split it out into two separate methods so that you can see its usage a bit clearer.

```
private String translateSuit(int suit) {
    switch(suit) {
        case 0:
            return "Clubs";
        case 1:
            return "Spades";
        case 2:
            return "Hearts";
        case 3:
            return "Diamonds";
     }
     // All conditions exhausted, no sense in continuing:
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid suit: " + suit);
}

private String translateRank(int card) {
    switch(card):
        case 1:
            return "Two";
        // fill in the rest here
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return translateRank(SUIT) + " of " + translateSuit(RANK)
           + " -- points: " + points;
}
```

Comment: I see, i never thought about using a switch loop here. I have another question that i will ask shortly after i implement something similar to this. :)

Comment: Both of these translate methods are private, does that mean what i assume it means? i've never seen a private method so far. These two wont be able to be accessed outside of this class but that wont matter because toString will be pushing it? @Makoto

Comment: Exactly.  Since no one else needs to know that those methods exist, there's no reason to expose them.

Comment: Im missing a return statement on my version of the first switch statement. In switch statemenets, depending on what is passed(the case), it will return whatever is in the block under it. So why would i be getting a missing return statement

Comment: Thank you, i'm not too familiar with switch statements is all. ty for hints and help tho. A better question would be what is Throw new illegalargumentexception? ive never seen it

Comment: I've revised my answer to include the "fall-through" case in which none of those suits match with your options.  This sorts out the compilation error, too.

Comment: Oh, didn't see this before posting my editted question above. Thanks for further clarification. And when in the switch we're returning "spades", "hearts" etc, where are these being returned to? because the trans method takes a int so where would the new String of this be found?

Comment: Im confused still on this throw new IllegalException. And at least in terms of my CardTest class testing what we've done with that block of code in the OP towards the top, it still fails. :/ AFTER TINKERING WITH THE TOSTRING METHOD I FIXED IT

Comment: I think it's time to phrase a new question about this.  Be sure that the code you have for it is in a condition such that everyone may observe the same failure you are (and be sure to specify the failure - it's very vague right now).

Comment: Good, idea just updated everything with a new question @Makoto